# Rounding in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, rounding

I want to ROUND Decimal values in sql server like  if the value is `1.1` then the result should be `2(next value)`. How to do it in sql server , any inbuilt method is there or i want to do manually?

**EDIT:**

If any value is der in Decimal place then also the result should be Next integer Value

Please Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mean to post a simplistic answer, but have you looked at [`CEILING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx) / [`FLOOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx)?

```
SELECT CEILING(1.1);

----
2
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx), `CEILING` "Returns the smallest integer greater than, or equal to, the specified numeric expression."

Comment: Thanks for the answer..`but If any value is der in Decimal place then also the result should be Next integer Value`..it will work by CEILING / FLOOR ?